# Can not update widget when data changed using Obx

Tags: flutter, daterangepicker

This is my view

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      flex: 3,
      child: Obx(
        () => TextFieldWidget(
            control: from,
            obsure: false,
            text: DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(controller.dateRange.value.start).toString(),
            callBackFunc: () async{
              controller.showDatePicker();
            },
            hint: true,),
        ),
    ),
    const Expanded(flex: 1, child: Icon(Icons.arrow_right_alt)),
    Expanded(
      flex: 3,
      child: Obx(
        () => TextFieldWidget(
            control: to,
            obsure: false,
            text: DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(controller.dateRange.value.end).toString(),
            callBackFunc: () async{
              controller.showDatePicker();
            },
            hint: true,),
      ),
    ),
    //TextFieldWidget(control:to_controller,obsure:false,text:'To'),
  ],
)};
```

my controller

```
Future showDatePicker() async{
final NewdateRange = await showDateRangePicker(
  context: Get.context!, 
  firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year-1),
  lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year+1),
  initialDateRange: dateRange.value,
  
);
if(NewdateRange != null && NewdateRange != dateRange.value){
  dateRange.value = NewdateRange;
  update();
}}
```

textfield widget I created

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return TextFormField(
  controller: control,
  obscureText: obsure,
  onTap: callBackFunc,
  onChanged: (text) => TextFieldWidget,
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: text,
    hintText: hint?text:'',
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
  ),
)};
```

I am flutter newbie, when I tab on textfield, datepicker showed, but when I saved the label text and hint text not update new date I was choose ?? Sorry for my poor English. Please help me !!!

Comment: can you provide full of `TextFieldWidget` ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/54f10n6r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you provide the full code, I can only say that a `TextField` will change value only when it is built in first time and through the controller, here `TextFieldWidget.text` is changed when `controller.dateRange` changed from `Obx`, but that won't re-initialize your `TextEditingController` so the value in the `TextField`s won't change.

To solve this, you need to listen for changes and call `control.text = newText` in `didUpdateWidget`.

**TextFieldWidget**

```
@override
void didUpdateWidget(Widget oldWidget) {
  if (oldWidget.text != widget.text) {
    control.text = widget.text;
  }
}
...
```